# iOS write to a file on ubuntu server

Tags: ios, ubuntu-server

does anyone know how to append a string from iOS on an existing file which is on an ubuntu server?
I tried the writeToURL method but it didn't work...

thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 2):

The writeToURL is meant to be used with "file://" protocol (e.g. locally), other network protocols are not supported (cf. [NSData – writeToURL:options:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/writeToURL%3aoptions%3aerror%3a)).

In order to send a string or upload a file to a remote server, it must have a dedicated service to handle the receipt. It can be a PHP script for example. 
The Objective-C code to write depends on the remote service.

So before anything else, you must first know what protocol to use in order to communicate with the remote server. After, you will need to experiment with [NSURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) classes.

In short: it's not possible to answer your question as we do not know more about your remote server.